# MxNet metrics API to compute accuracy for multiclass logistic regression with vector labels

Tags: python, logistic-regression, mxnet, multiclass-classification

How to use MxNet [metrics api](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/metric/metric.html) to calculate accuracy of the **multiclass** logistic regression classifier with vector labels?
Here is an example for labels:

```
Class1: [1,0,0,0]
Class2: [0,1,0,0]
Class3: [0,0,1,0]
Class4: [0,0,0,1]
```

The naive way to use this function would produce wrong result as argmax will squash the model output into an index having max probability value

```
def evaluate_accuracy(data_iterator, ctx, net):
    acc = mx.metric.Accuracy()
    for i, (data, label) in enumerate(data_iterator):
        data = data.as_in_context(ctx)
        label = label.as_in_context(ctx)
        out = net(data)
        p = nd.argmax(out, axis=1)
        acc.update(preds=p, labels=label)
    return acc.get()[1]
```

My current solution is little hacky:

```
def evaluate_accuracy(data_iterator, ctx, net):
    acc = mx.metric.Accuracy()
    for i, (data, label) in enumerate(data_iterator):
        data = data.as_in_context(ctx)
        label = label.as_in_context(ctx)
        out = net(data)
        p = nd.argmax(out, axis=1)
        l = nd.argmax(label, axis=1)
        acc.update(preds=p, labels=l)
    return acc.get()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Accuracy](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/metric/metric.html#mxnet.metric.Accuracy) metric is tricky. It doesn't really work with one-hot-encoded labels as a ground-truth.

I find this somewhat counter-intuitive, but you need to pass non-one-hot-encoded labels as a ground-truth, but actual classes (eg, 2 instead of [0,0,1,0]). Otherwise, accuracy would not work in the way you expect. Take a look into my previous reply here - [Why MXNet is reporting the incorrect validation accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798125/why-mxnet-is-reporting-the-incorrect-validation-accuracy/48471241)

Also, MxNet expect classes to start with 0. So, if you have classes starting from 1, then you need to adjust all classes by subtracting 1.

Comment: Thanks Sergei. I guess this should be a bug then, since SoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss allows for labels having probability distributions, but metrics API doesn't account for this.

Comment: @Sergey, btw you can answer this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217210/why-normalizing-labels-in-mxnet-makes-accuracy-close-to-100 it looks like 0 based labels is a reason there